# on click showing confirmation box

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I'm new in web development. I want to create a function which will show a confirm box by clicking on delete button (if row selected). I have also try to make it, my function working properly but i want to show confirm box only when row or rows will selected other wise it will show "**Please select row first**". Please help me

### My code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button"  value="Delete" onclick="javascript: var c=confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete selected members?'); if(c==false) return false; ">
```

this is selection code

```
function checkall()
{
    //alert("Hi");
    var length=document.listing_form.elements['ids[]'].length;
    //alert(length);
    for(var c1=0;c1<length;c1++)
        document.listing_form.elements['ids[]'][c1].checked=true;
} // ends
```

I'm unable to add image due to the low number of reputation so I have added a [**link**](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mw002mGqNqo/U5AJ8neLekI/AAAAAAAAAbk/bD1ysNWQCzM/s1600/image.png) kindly visit and understand to my question.

Comment: I have got banners rows from database on this page

Comment: So what? Show code please! How can we help you otherwise?

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` prefix in `onXXX` attributes. That's only needed when JS is being used in place of a URL, such as in `href`.

Comment: I have already show my confirm box code. I need only confirm box when rows will selected. If you don't understand to my question I will add my page screen shot..?

Comment: @Barmar but its working properly

Comment: @user3698265 I know. I said you don't _need_ it. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: "only when row or rows will selected" - do you really don't understand that I don't know how are they coded? So, ok your code is `if(any-row-is-selected){do-your-code}`. I don't see any more information about rows.

Comment: No need in image. We need **CODE**. **CODE**. **CODE**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ok_to_delete() {
    if (rows_selected()) {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected members?");
    } else {
        alert("Please select a row first.");
        return false;
    }
}

function rows_selected() {
    var ids = document.listing_form.elements['ids[]'];
    var length = ids.length;
    for (var c1 = 0; c1 < length; c1++) {
        if (ids[c1].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Your form should then contain:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return ok_to_delete()">
```

Comment: what will rows_selected() ...?

Comment: I have used following code for all rows selection

function checkall()
{
 //alert("Hi");
 var length=document.listing_form.elements['ids[]'].length;
 //alert(length);
 for(var c1=0;c1<length;c1++)
  document.listing_form.elements['ids[]'][c1].checked=true;
} // ends

Comment: That looks like you know enough to be able to write a function that tests whether any of them are checked.

Comment: NO i'm unabele to make rows_selected fucntion. Please make it for me, help please...

Comment: I'm new in web development have low knowledge of JavaScript please do it

Comment: OK, I've written it for you. It's the same kind of loop you wrote to check all the boxes, but instead of checking them it tests whether any is checked. I don't understand how you can write that function and not be able to come up with this, it's such similar logic.

Comment: Really you have good knowledge of development and ability to understand others problems..I appreciate your help...Thanks again @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

since you're using a submit button, you're better off adding this to the form tag itself, like the code below.  if the confirm returns true, then the form will submit.  otherwise, you will just return back to the page and submission will not continue.

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirmThis()">
<input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button"  value="Delete" />
</form>

<script>
  function confirmThis() {
      return confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete selected members?");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? He wants to display an alert "Please select a row first" if the user hasn't selected a row.

Comment: I have already use this function @gerald what i want? I want add two condition by clicking on delete button.
1- If row or rows not selected function will display "please select row"
2- IF row or rows will selected function will display "Are you sure to delete selected members?"

Comment: @Barmar The question is anyway unanswerable now. Because we don't know anything about rows, and OP doesn't understand it.

Comment: @user3698265 "If row or rows not selected". How do we help you???? We don't know how the rows CODED!

Comment: I'm unable to add image due to the low number of reputation so visit the link I hope to understand my question
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mw002mGqNqo/U5AJ8neLekI/AAAAAAAAAbk/bD1ysNWQCzM/s1600/image.png

Comment: @user3698265 Ok. Then the answer Barmar's answer is right. UNTIL you show us more **CODE**.

Comment: @user3698265 Show the rows code. Please. Or, at least, give a link to your website. (if it is website)

Comment: @Barmar, good question.  the OP question now that i reread it is completely different than what i thought i read.  oh well, it looks like the question was answered.  note to self: read the question well before answering.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some kind of click handler that will select your rows.. so if:

```
<table id="rows">
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

You would need something like this:

```
var _table, _tr;
function rowSelect() {
    _table = document.getElementById("rows");
    _tr = _table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < _tr.length; i++) {
            _tr[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                if(_tr[i].className.indexOf('selected')>-1) {
                    // deselect
                    _tr[i].className = _tr[i].className.replace("selected", "");
                }
                else {
                    // select
                    _tr[i].className = _tr[i].className + " selected";
                }
            }, false);
    }
}

function confirm() {
     if (checkSelected()) {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected members?");
    } else {
        alert("Please select a row first.");
        return false;
    }
}

function checkSelected() {
    for (var i = 0; i < _tr.length; i++) {
        if (_tr[i].className.indexOf('selected')>-1) return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

let me know if you have any questions.